# Differences in bash scripts between $@ and $*

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

Which are the differences between `$@` and `$*` ?
For example I see no differences here:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo with star: $*
echo with at sign: $@
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When they're not quoted, there is no difference between `$@` and `$*`. Both are equal to `$1` `$2` … But don't do this.

With double quotes, `"$@"` expands each element as an argument:

> `"$1"` `"$2"` …

while `"$*"` expands to all elements merged into one argument:

> `"$1c$2c..."`

where `c` is the first character of `IFS`. If you unset `IFS`, `c` will be a space.

You almost always want `"$@"`. The same goes for arrays: `"${myarray[@]}"`

Comment: I only disagree with the last statement. I use "$*" expansion with IFS all the time. It's as useful as `array.join` in other languages. You can even use it to break lines: Whereas `printf '%s\n' "$@"` will have a trailing linebreak, `printf '%s' "$*"` with `IFS='\n'` will not.

Comment: (Sorry, that should be `IFS=$'\n'`.)

Answer (score 3):

@sputnick has the right answer. To demonstrate with an example:\

```
# use two positional parameters, each with whitespace
set -- "one two" "three four"

# demonstrate the various forms with the default $IFS
echo '$*:'
printf ">%s<\n" $*
echo '$@:'
printf ">%s<\n" $@
echo '"$*":'
printf ">%s<\n" "$*"
echo '"$@":'
printf ">%s<\n" "$@"

# now with a custom $IFS
(
IFS=:
echo '$*:'
printf ">%s<\n" $*
echo '$@:'
printf ">%s<\n" $@
echo '"$*":'
printf ">%s<\n" "$*"
echo '"$@":'
printf ">%s<\n" "$@"
)
```

outputs

```
$*:
>one<
>two<
>three<
>four<
$@:
>one<
>two<
>three<
>four<
"$*":
>one two three four<
"$@":
>one two<
>three four<
$*:
>one two<
>three four<
$@:
>one two<
>three four<
"$*":
>one two:three four<
"$@":
>one two<
>three four<
```

Comment: Hoo boy, does this answer needs some explanation... anyone with some time is welcome to pitch in.