# Is there a way to pass a statement via an argument in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

What I'm trying to achieve is to set the title of a widget when computer goes to idle:

```
xsidle.sh echo mywidget.title = "idle" | awesome-client
```

when i remove `xsidle.sh` it works flawlessly. `xsidle.sh` is roughly:

```
sleep 10
command="$1"
$command
```

Of course the output of xsidle is redirected to awesome-client, while I'm trying to echo to awesome-client with a delay.

I've tried escaping with " or ', the echo output is "`mywidget.title = "idle" | awesome-client`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
"$@"
```

If you have nothing more to do after the command, you can use

```
exec "$@"
```

This is in your friendly manual page (try `man sh`), although it is not so easy to know how to find it.
See also questions such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/538985/differences-in-bash-scripts-between-and).