# bash function equivalent to an alias

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a better way to write a bash function equivalent to an alias and does this work in all cases? It seems OK (edit: it's not).

```
alias g="git"
g(){ git `echo $@ |xargs`;}
typeset -f g
```

Comment: To have an alias with arguments you need to create a function. Not very sure what you are pretending to do here.

Comment: You're making it needlessly complex: all you need is `g(){ git "$@"; }`. The `typedef` is implicit.

Comment: ...but the double-quotes @AFH added around `$@` are very strongly recommended.

Comment: thanks. I did find a problem with my method when trying to do `g ci -m "multiple words"`. I'll use the simple "$@" from now on

Answer (score 0):

Few problems with your approach:

- [`echo` is not reliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618);
- [you need `"$@"`, not `$@`](https://superuser.com/a/538986/432690), the latter will break the code if you pass an argument with spaces (e.g. `"multiple words"`).

The right way:

```
g(){ git "$@"; }
```